# Placing comma inside or outside of quotation marks in mid-sentence

Tags: commas

When emphasizing a word with quotes in the middle of the sentence, do you put the commma before or after quotation marks?

Example:  heard a lot about the word "quarantine," referring to preventive

Comment: It's a pure matter of style, but I place punctuation outside the quotes. Here it's used more for emphasis or to express the author's reflections on language use, but if it is a literal quotation that contains a full sentence, then I include both the original punctuation inside the quote and my own outside, for example: `The policeman shouted "Stop!".`

Comment: The truth is that while there are plentiful opinions about it, nobody really cares except certain copy editors and certain schoolteachers. Because nobody else ever notices.

Comment: @JasonBassford, you may be right about the style guide, that's why I say it's a matter of style.